# Scraping utf-8 web pages with some wrong (incomplete) character

Tags: xml, r, httr

Trying to scraping web pages from an Italian blog (all pages are formatted in the same way, and have  the 'meta charset="utf-8" ' tag), the result is ok for some pages, it's ko for others.

Looking at the page source from the browser, I noticed that there are two meta-tag with the first N characters of the post (the tags are **meta name="description" content="..."** and **meta property="og:description" content="..."**, respectively showing the first 200 and 600 characters of the post).
If at least one of these two string ends truncating the n bytes of the last character (this happens if the last character is a smart quote, or an accented vowel... any character using 2,3, or 4 bytes in UTF-8), the page is NOT correctly processed.

Here's the code:

```
library(httr)
url_OK <- "http://odifreddi.blogautore.repubblica.it/2015/07/06/e-ora-un-referendum-in-europa/"
html0 <- GET(url_OK)
content0 <- content(html0, as="text")
nchar(content0)  # -> 85767 : that's okay

url_KO <- "http://odifreddi.blogautore.repubblica.it/2013/12/06/lacrime-di-coccodrillo-per-mandela/"
html1 <- GET(url_KO)
content1 <- content(html1, as="text")
nchar(content1)  # -> 2 : it's NA!
```

I tried also with httpget, but all the particular characters (as accented vowels) are missed:

```
html1 <- RCurl::httpGET(url_KO)
foo <- xmlInternalTreeParse(html1, asText=TRUE, isHTML=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
foo1 <- getNodeSet(foo,"//div[@class='article-maincolblog']")  # retry the text of the post
foo1
```

I'd like to know if there is some way to obtain the correct content, having discarded the incorrect (incomplete) utf-8 characters, thank you!

Comment: There is a typo in your code. `urlKO` and `url_KO`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials (with a lot of different functions), I found a workaround using tau::readChars :

```
 resu <- download.file(url_KO, "temp.htm")   # save the web page to disk
 stopifnot (resu==0)
 html1 <- readChars(file("temp.htm"), encoding="UTF-8")
```

This works.